# Need guidance on how to create Mobile App right from creation to Deployment to Running

Tags: mobile, ibm-cloud

Require help in IBM Bluemix for 
1) Mobile App creation , screens and relevant data on each along with authentication
2) Screens to show data (can be hard coded and not necessarily from the API calls)
3) compiling the Mobile APP and
4) Running the APP and testing on device

New to IBM Bluemix and unaware of the products and usability

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question can best be answered if you search on examples and tutorials available in GitHub and from IBM developerWorks. Stack Overflow is for specific questions that come up while you are developing code, not for general education and assistance. For an explanation of the kinds of questions that get answered here, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the [Bluemix Mobile Dashboard](https://console.bluemix.net/mobile/getting-started/) and try to [Create a Bluemix Mobile project](https://console.bluemix.net/mobile/create-project/). 
From there you will be able to configure your mobile app with the set of UI starters available and/or integrate your mobile app with your personal, auto deployed, Bluemix mobile enabled services. All without writing a single line of code! Try it out, build an auto generated mobile app, and let me know how it goes!